# In python, why do some byte strings have \x in them, and others dont?

Tags: python, types, byte

Im struggling to understand why and how some python byte strings have `\x` in them, and others dont.

For example, I have this assertion:

```
AssertionError: 
actual b'00000001'
expected b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

Why are they not equal? They are both byte strings, 4 bytes long with a value 1. How do I make them look the same, and how do I make them "be" the same? It seems one has come from a string string, and the other made from integer - but why dont they come out the same when converted to bytes?

Hopefully I've not missed something else.

Thanks

Comment: One is hexadecimal and the other is not.

Comment: Take the `len` of each byte string and you'll see they are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same thing.  The `\x` denotes a hexadecimal value.

Without the `\x` it is just a raw byte string with each character representing it's own integer value.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> a = b'00000001'
>>> b = b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> int.from_bytes(a, 'little')
3544385890265608240
>>> int.from_bytes(b, 'little')
16777216
>>> len(a)
8
>>> len(b)
4
>>> a.hex()
'3030303030303031'
>>> b.hex()
'00000001'
>>> a[0]
48
>>> b[0]
0
```

Also, since we can see from above that `b'0'` is represented by `48` and since `48 = 16*3` that means `b'\x30'` should be equal to `b'0'`

```
>>> b'0' == b'\x30'
True
```